# iFrame height not returning properly in IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, height

I've researched this yet most people seem to be having the opposite problem as I am, where their solution is to use the code that I've already applied. I'm dynamically sizing my iFrames based on their content, and it works like a charm in Chrome and FF. IE does not work. Code is below. Thank you.

```
function resizeIframe(iframe) {
                iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";

               /*
                 iframe.height = "500px" - this worked fine in all browsers
               */
    }


<iframe id="exampleIframe" onload="resizeIframe(this);" />
```

Answer edited to include `+ "px"`, which now works in Chrome & FF, but still not IE.

Comment: Have you tried using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)?

Comment: `iframe.setAttribute("height", iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px");`


Same situation; Works in Chrome, no luck in FF/IE.

Comment: Does the iframe src come from the same domain? ... If not, then that answers the question, you hit the cross origin block.

Comment: Yes, the pages are in the same directory.

Comment: Tested now, in IE11, and it works as is but I needed to add  `'px'`

Comment: Interesting! Adding `'px'` actually made the page work in Firefox, but IE is still being stubborn. I must not have checked Firefox when I made that change originally. Definitely getting closer, I'll have to keep playing with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!

I was declaring a default parameter in an earlier function by doing `function functionName(param = false){}`

IE did not agree with this method, and so the block failed. Due to this, resizeIframe() was not found and so the Iframe did not resize.

By instead doing default parameters like this:

```
function functionName(param) { 
     if (typeof param == "undefined") {
           param = "Default";
     } 
}
```

Thank you everyone.